# Enclosed functions variable

Tags: javascript, function, object, private, stampit.js

I started to read the source code for stampit js yesterday, and found an interesting way of enclose function variables in an object by calling apply()

```
instance = fn.apply(instance, arguments) || instance;
```

How does this really work?
And why does the following code line not work?

```
instance = fn.apply(instance, arguments);
```

A longer example:

```
var createFoo = function() {
    var foo = {},
        fn = function() {
            var i = 0;

            this.increment = function() {
                i++;
            };

            this.get = function() {
                return i;
            };
        };
    foo = fn.apply(foo, arguments) || foo;
    return foo;
}, foo = createFoo();

test('foo test', function () {
    foo.increment();
    equal(foo.get(), 1, 'pass');
});

var createBar = function() {
    var bar = {},
        fn = function() {
            var i = 0;

            this.increment = function() {
                i++;
            };

            this.get = function() {
                return i;
            };
        };
    bar = fn.apply(bar, arguments);
    return bar;
}, bar = createBar();

test('bar tests', function () {
    bar.increment(); /* undefined */
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RMh78/59/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: What's different between the 2 lines you posted at the top?

Comment: When you have `a || b`, this will evaluate `a` and return it if it's "truthy", otherwise it'll return `b`.

Comment: Sorry Rocket Hazmat, it was a typo. It is changed now.

Answer (score 2):

What's going here has to do with how objects are passed as references and what values functions return.

In your code block, you have:

```
var createFoo = function() {
    var foo = {},
        fn = function() {
            var i = 0;

            this.increment = function() {
                i++;
            };

            this.get = function() {
                return i;
            };
        };
    foo = fn.apply(foo, arguments) || foo;
    return foo;
},
foo = createFoo();
```

Let's break down the `foo = fn.apply(foo, arguments) || foo;` line.

`foo` was declared and initialized as an empty object (`{}`).  It was then set as the `this` context in the `foo` function (that's what `.apply` does).  The `arguments` would pass any args (none) sent to `createFoo` to `fn`.

So, so when `fn.apply` is ran, the `foo` objects has `increment` and `get` properties applied to it.  `fn` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

So, now we have `foo = undefined || foo;`, and we have `foo` updated with some properties.  This sets `foo` to itself, then the next line returns it.

In the second (`bar`) block:

```
var createBar = function() {
    var bar = {},
        fn = function() {
            var i = 0;

            this.increment = function() {
                i++;
            };

            this.get = function() {
                return i;
            };
        };
    bar = fn.apply(bar, arguments);
    return bar;
},
bar = createBar();
```

You don't have `|| bar` after `fn.apply(bar, arguments)`.  So, what happens is that `fn` runs, it returns `undefined`, `bar`'s set to that then `bar` (`undefined`) is returned.

Answer (score 0):

So how does the following code work, and does it have any disadvantages compared to the first    createFoo function?

```
var createFoo2 = function() {
    var foo = {},
    fn = function() {
        var i = 0;

        this.increment = function() {
            i++;
        };

        this.get = function() {
            return i;
        };
    };
    fn.apply(foo, arguments);
    return foo;
},
foo2 = createFoo2();
```